# How to count the number of of children for a parent in the new firebase version 9 using numChildren()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to count the number of of children for a parent in the new firebase version 9 using `numChildren()`?

This is how it is done in firebase version 8 below

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).on('value', (snapData) => {
      console.log(snapData.numChildren())
    })
```

But in version 9 this isn't working below

```
   onValue(ref(db, 'users/'), (snapData) => {
      console.log(snapData.numChildren())
    })
```

Does anyone know how it is done in firebase version 9 `numChildren()`?

Comment: There is no direct equivalent.  You will have to convert the snapshot to a `val()`, check if it is a javascript object that has children, then count the properties on that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `numChildren` anymore in v9, but you can get the same value with"

```
onValue(ref(db, 'users/'), (snapData) => {
  console.log(Object.keys(snapData.val()).length) // 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Frank got it right, there is no numChildren anymore, but his answer produces an error if there is no value in the db

snapData.val() will be null and you can't Object.keys(null)

so it's:

```
onValue(ref(db, 'users/'), (snapData) => {
    const count = snapData.exists() && Object.keys(snapData.val()).length || 0;
})
```

Docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.datasnapshot